# C lang strlen function returns wrong value

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void func(char* str) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8191; i += 1) {
        str[i] = ('a');
    }
}
int main(void) {
    char buff[8192] = { 0, };
    int len = 0;
    
    func(buff);// printf("%s\n", buff);
    len = strlen(buff);
    printf("len:%d\n");
    //printf("%s\n",buff);
    return 0;
}
```

I try to expect the len : 8191 ,
but returns wrong number..
why is this happen??
could you explain why this happens??

Comment: Does it even print a number?

Comment: @debug0x1231 Change the compiler or the programming language.:)

Comment: @debug0x1231 It is interesting to know what value you got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf("len:%d\n");` is incorrect. For each conversion specification such as `%d`, there must be an argument in the function call that gives the value to be printed. It should be `printf("len:%d\n", len);`.

Your compiler likely warned you of this. If it did not, enable warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them.